# Can ssh-copy-id respect my ssh config?

Tags: ssh, scripting, access-control

I store all my keys outside of `.ssh` and configured which key to use for which server in my `.ssh/config`. How can I make `ssh-copy-id` respect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless anyone comes up with some unknown flag, I'll go with a simple wrapper:

```bsh
sshci() {
  ssh-copy-id -i "$(ssh -G "$1" | grep "^identityfile " | head -1 | cut -d " " -f2- | sed "s|^~|$HOME|")" "$1"
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304271/bash-extract-user-for-a-particular-host-from-ssh-config-file was of great help in creating this :)

Comment: Why do you need all of that? Just use the full path to the public key. `ssh-copy-id` doesn't care.

Comment: because I don't want to remember which key I use for which machine

Comment: You don't have to remember anything. You only have to do it once. After that, you just connect via `ssh`. You are complicating things where it isn't necessary and placing an undue burden on yourself. No one in their right mind would do anything this tedious and unnecessary. What you've done is more difficult that what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes, I have to do it once for every machine I connect to, and I use different keys for different types of machines to improve security.

Comment: It doesn't improve security in any measurable way. I work at a healthcare institution and have worked at several others as well as financial and insurance institutions and none of them have done this. Even if you insisted on it, then you would still need to the location of each key for `ssh-copy-id`. After that was done, you wouldn't need to anymore which defeats the purpose of your convoluted command.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the institution. It is about separating my accesses to entirely different spaces (personal VM, company, git pushes).

Comment: I was using them as examples. Security is important in those institutions and no one does that. Bottom line, what you are doing doesn't improve security. The purpose of using SSH keys is not to send passwords across a network(s). That's already achieved just by having one. It also does nothing separate your access as it's all coming from the same place. If machine is compromised, then the intruder is going to have access to anywhere that you've sent the public key so you've done nothing for security with your convoluted command.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
ssh-copy-id -i {{the key you want to copy}} 
     {{the Host config name in ~/.ssh/config file}}
```